# Why do the photos taken on my HTC One X not have a date/time displayed on them?

Tags: camera, htc-one-x

When I take a photo on my HTC One X, the date and time that the picture was taken do not appear appear (printed) on the photo. I can't set the date or time in the settings, either. If I use a third party application, I can set the date/time and see the timestamp on the photo.

My old HTC Legend (Gingerbread) had an option to choose whether the timestamp would appear or not.

Is it a feature not supported by Android 4.x, or is it just because of HTC One X model? It was not present on Ice Cream Sandwich or since I've upgraded to Jelly Bean.

Comment: What do you mean by "appear on the photo": "Printed" on top of the picture, or are you talking about EXIF tags inside the file? Aside from that, you should always have the timestamp of the image file. I never saw timestamps *printed* on top of the picture with digital cams, though it is no problem technically (and there might be apps supporting it directly).

Comment: sorry for the misleading usage. I mean example [ 05 Dec 2012 15:27PM ] printed on the corner of Photo Image. Not the tag inside the file.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! See my answer below in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is rather be app-specific. Probably the default photo app on your Legend does this by default, while the one on you One X does not. To achieve the desired results on your new device, you might need to find a 3rd party photo app supporting this feature. Your phone is certainly capable of it, that's not the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really wonder why the default app of One X doesn't support this. :(

Comment: I rather wonder why the default app on the Legend did that -- except if you needed to turn on this feature explicitly. That's a quite old feature from 35mm film cameras (where it made sense) which does no longer make sense with digital photos, where this information is available with file and EXIF information and thus can be "printed" or not just on demand. I wouldn't want to have that on my photos :)

Comment: on Legend, I can turn on and off. Not by default. I just want to have default app of One X supports that kind of turn on and off feature :)

Comment: OK -- that makes perfectly sense now :) Might want to take a look at [PhotoCap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.atup.PhotoCap) or [UCam Ultra Kamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ucamera.ucam), which seem to offer this feature. If one of them is acceptable as a solution, let me know, and I add it to the answer test.

Comment: Thanks Izzy. I am using Camera360 at the moment. Will check out those apps suggested by you too :D